# Minimize the space between two bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

[image]

Hey guys,

I have this image.

And this Code:

```
def Gender_Distribution(Land1_df, Land2_df): 
Gender_per = Land1_df.loc[Land1_df.Gender.isin(["Man", "Woman", "Nonbinary"]), ["Gender"]].value_counts(normalize = True).reset_index().T.rename(index={ 0 : 'America'})
Gender_per2 = Land2_df.loc[Land2_df.Gender.isin(["Man", "Woman", "Nonbinary"]), ["Gender"]].value_counts(normalize = True).reset_index().T.rename(index = { 0 : "China"})
Gender_per = Gender_per.rename(columns = Gender_per.iloc[0])
Gender_per = Gender_per.drop('Gender')
Gender_per2 = Gender_per2.rename(columns = Gender_per2.iloc[0])
Gender_per2 = Gender_per2.drop('Gender')

Gender_per = pd.concat([Gender_per, Gender_per2])


fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5))
                   
Gender_per.plot(kind = 'barh', stacked = True, ax = ax, color = colors2)


for (x, y) in zip(Gender_per.iloc[0],Gender_per.iloc[0].cumsum()):
    plt.text(x=((y-x)+(x/2)), y=0,s=f'{np.round(x * 100,1)}%',fontsize=12,ha='center') 

for (x, y) in zip(Gender_per.iloc[1],Gender_per.iloc[1].cumsum()):
    plt.text(x=((y-x)+(x/2)), y=1,s=f'{np.round(x * 100,1)}%',fontsize=12,ha='center') 


ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=1))

ax.legend(Gender_per.columns, loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.47,1), frameon=False,ncol=len(Gender_per.columns), prop={'size': 12})

plt.grid(False)

ax.text(0.0, 1.7, "Participants of America by age in %",fontsize=20, fontweight="bold")
ax.text(0.03, 1.52, "China's Participants are more male Dominated as the USA" ,fontsize=14)

ax.set_facecolor("whitesmoke")
fig.set_facecolor("whitesmoke")

return plt.show()
```

I want now to minimize the Space between the two horizontal bars. How can i do it?

Comment: Set width=0.95 in the plot call